# WPF BitmapFrame and multiple threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, bitmap

I have a PNG file stored in my cloud in blob storage, I want to download it and render it on the screen in WPF.

I know about the Dispatcher and Freezing, but nothing is working. I keep getting the error about "another thread owns it".

Here is what I have:

```
var decoder = GetDecoder("http://address/image.png");

Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action<BitmapFrame>(SetImage), decoder.Frames[0]);

public void SetImage(BitmapFrame source)
{
    var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(source);  //ERROR HERE!!!!!!!!
    LazyImage.Source = bitmapFrame;
}

private BitmapDecoder GetDecoder(object uri)
{
    var extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension((string)uri);
    BitmapDecoder decoder = null;
    if (extension.ToLower() == ".png")
        decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri((string)uri, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    return decoder;
}
```

If i try to freeze the Frame[0] I get an exception saying that this Frame cannot be frozen. Also the Decoder returned by `BitmapDecoder.Create` is **not** a `PngBitmapDecoder` but a `LateBoundBitmapDecoder` which I dont really know how to use effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible that you need to not only create the Bitmapframe on the dispatcher but also the BitmapDecoder? Have you tried invoking the GetDecoder on the dispatcher?

Comment: perhaps, I think the creation of the decoder is a synchronous operation which means that I would like to avoid it happening on the UI thread. Mind you, files on my local PC (not http URL's) works fine as it is, because the decoder is a `PngBitmapDecoder`

Comment: Well... its possible that maybe you can call BitmapFrame.Create() in a thread, and attempt to freeze the frame it returns?

Comment: If I freeze the frame returned by the LateBoundBitmapDecoder, I get an exception, but if I use a local URL (and hence the PngBitmapDecoder) I can freeze it and it works just fine.

Comment: Was lookin around and found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e76d4534-8f92-44be-a3d7-8bfa2ca9600d/

Scroll down to Dwayne Need's answer, he has some source for a demo that does async loading, which should bypass the issue you are having.

Comment: Ok, looks like my issues were larger related to the fact that I created a BitmapImage on a BG thread and tried to pass it to a UI thread, but for some reason I could not clone or freeze it, so I just ended up passing a byte[] to the UI thread and contructing an image using that... Ill give you the points because you were the only one who answered

Answer (score 5):

In brief: try wrapping the result into a `WriteableBitmap`.

[Long story, with code.](http://modosansreves-coding.blogspot.com/2011/12/jpegbitmapencoder-and-tlp-finally-got.html)

Comment: For my case, this was the only solution that worked. I needed to feed a BitmapFrame into a TransformedBitmap. Didn't have control over which thread the BitmapFrame was created on as it is provided by a library (and BitmapFrame's Dispatcher property is null). Even querying the CanFreeze property caused an exception. I had two options: major overhaul of the source code of mine and others, or use WriteableBitmap. Guess which one i chose...

Answer (score 1):

This is still a problem today! Wrapping the data in `WriteableBitmap` as suggested by Bohdan will work, but that type has a front and back buffer which doubles its memory footprint. `CachedBitmap` is a better choice.

```
new CachedBitmap(bitmapSource, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

Use `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` unless you like surprises, and remember to freeze the resulting object too.