# PngBitmapEncoder failling

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, png

I'm loading bitmaps on one thread, and then later saving them to disk on another thread.

Loading on Thread A :

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = null;
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    bitmapSource = BitmapDecoder
        .Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames[0];
    bitmapSource.Freeze();
}

// only available to Thread B at this point (i.e after loading is complete).
```

Saving on Thread B :

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(bitmapSource.IsFrozen);
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource)); <-- Exception here
...
```

99% of the time, this works fine. But every once in a while, I'll get an exception at the 'BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource)' point, with the following call stack :

```
     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
       at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.get_IsDownloading()
       at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.get_InternalMetadata()
       at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(BitmapSource source)

The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

I'm really not sure what is going on. From my understanding, as long as you freeze the bitmapsource, you can access it from another thread? I also have a debug assert to check it is frozen, which never gets triggered. And if I check all the properties of the bitmapsource object in the debugger, I see the following :

[image]

All properties are accessable apart from the IsDownloading one. I'm not doing any downloading. I'm loading the bitmap from disk, and it's not available to the second thread until its completed loading? so it's a bit of a mystery, at least to me.

Comment: You may directly call `bitmapSource = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);` The returned BitmapFrame should already be frozen.

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the properties and you can see it says it's frozen, yet for some reason, calling Create checks the IsDownloading property, which causes the exception

Answer (score 1):

I came across this :

[WPF BitmapFrame and multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940447/wpf-bitmapframe-and-multiple-threads)

The solution appears to be to wrap the bitmap in a `CachedBitmap`

```cs
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(new CachedBitmap(x, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad)));
```

Ideally, you could use `CheckAccess()` to determine it this extra step is necessary rather than always doing it, but CheckAccess() always returns true for some reason.